# Dockable fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments in my activity. One of them is a listfragment.

I want to make the listfragment dockable, any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by dockable?

Comment: I should be able to move it in the tablet viewing space. Just like we change the location of say the logcat tab in eclipse